# Refreshing PayPal OAuth token

Tags: paypal, oauth, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I develop payout system which is based on PayPal's payouts.
To make a call to PayPal API it is neccessary to get OAuth token as described in

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

I found that repeatedly calls to get OAuth token don't refresh it (the token gets the same, expiration time decreases).

Is there any way to force OAuth token refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your payment system, the short-lived access token can be used immediately for a payment or an authorization/capture. The refresh token is long-lived (currently 10 years), and must be stored securely.

For any future payment or authorization/capture, since the access token will have expired, use the refresh token to get a new access token for use calling the Payment API. For more info check the Exchange the auth code for refresh and access tokens https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/make-future-payment/

Comment: My pay system is just a service that hidden from user. The only thing it does is sending payouts from its own business application account to users. So I use my app's client_id and client_secret to get OAuth token for further payouts. But when I get PayPal OAuth token, I see no refresh_token field in http response or smth like this. How can I refresh the token without waiting expire_in time to get an exception and get another access token manually after an error?